# Two-circulant matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

How to construct a two-circulant matrix?

For example, the following matrix `A` is two-circulant, i.e every column (expect from the first one) is obtained from the previous one by putting the last two elements as first. Note that the first column is the generator of the matrix.

```
N=12
k=6
x=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
A=matrix(0,N,k)
A[,1]=x
for( j in 2:ncol(A) )
{
A[,j]=c(A[11:12,j-1],A[1:10,j-1])
}

> A
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    0    2    2    1    1    0
 [2,]    0    2    2    1    1    0
 [3,]    0    0    2    2    1    1
 [4,]    0    0    2    2    1    1
 [5,]    1    0    0    2    2    1
 [6,]    1    0    0    2    2    1
 [7,]    1    1    0    0    2    2
 [8,]    1    1    0    0    2    2
 [9,]    2    1    1    0    0    2
[10,]    2    1    1    0    0    2
[11,]    2    2    1    1    0    0
[12,]    2    2    1    1    0    0
```

Is there any other way to constuct the matrix `A`? For example by using a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
circular_matrix <- function(x, ncol) {

 coll <- list(x)
 for (i in 1:(ncol-1)) {

  current <- coll[[length(coll)]]
  coll[[length(coll) + 1]] <- c(tail(current, 2), current[1:(length(current) - 2)])

 }

 do.call(cbind, coll)

}

circular_matrix(1:10, 5)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    9    7    5    3
# [2,]    2   10    8    6    4
# [3,]    3    1    9    7    5
# [4,]    4    2   10    8    6
# [5,]    5    3    1    9    7
# [6,]    6    4    2   10    8
# [7,]    7    5    3    1    9
# [8,]    8    6    4    2   10
# [9,]    9    7    5    3    1
#[10,]   10    8    6    4    2
```